# How to add a custom class to my JQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, class, user-interface, datepicker

I have several inputs which trigger JQuery UI datepickers e.g.

```
<input id="one" type="text"/>
<input id="two" type="text"/>
<input id="three" type="text"/>
<input id="four" type="text"/>
```

For each jquery UI datepicker created, I want to assign a custom class based on the ID of the input which triggered it i.e. `.one`, `.two`, `.three`

So if the datepicker is triggered by the first input the resulting HTML will look like:

```
  <div class="one ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" id="ui-datepicker-div">
```

Note the first class `one`

Is this possible? The '`create`' method of the datepicker does not seem to work for me...

Comment: This question is unclear. Add JS code you have so far and point out more closely what you want to do.

Comment: I have edited the question - what is unclear? I want to add a class to each of the datepicker div's the class name should be the same as the ID of the element which triggered the datepicker.

Comment: Not impossible (as I seem to remember hacking something together to change some CSS in the past) but there is actually only one `<div class="ui-datepicker">` element, no matter how many `<input>`s you have.

Comment: I know but I still need this functionality

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`beforeShow` can be used to manipulate the `class` before showing the *datepicker*.

```
$('input').datepicker({
   beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
       $('#ui-datepicker-div').removeClass(function() {
           return $('input').get(0).id; 
       });
       $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass(this.id);
   }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ggwGs/) (using jQuery 1.6.2 but needs jQuery > v1.4 for the [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) which takes a function)

**Note** This works by removing all the classes (i.e. `<input>` `id`s) with a **general `$('input')` selector which you might want to limit to just pick up the `<input>` elements that have been modified into date pickers.

**Edit** Just had an upvote for this and looking at the code, it did not seem to do what I explained it should (maybe I misunderstood the question!). So, here is a version which adds a class equal to the `id` of the `<input>` clicked on to the datepicker. Also uses the original `.removeClass()` so this will work with jQuery > v1.2.

```
var inputIds = $('input').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get().join(' '); // space separated ready for removeClass

$('input').datepicker({
   beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
       $('#ui-datepicker-div').removeClass(inputIds);
       $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass(this.id);
   }
});​
```

Comment: `$('#ui-datepicker-div')` can be replaced by `inst.dpDiv` for a cleaner/better solution :)

Comment: This affects all datepicker on the site, not just the current one, and even those not binded with $('input').datepicker();

Comment: @xcy7e웃 there is only one datepicker. This has always been the case with jQueryUI. It doesn't matter how many times it is used. There is only 1 added to the DOM. This solution correctly adds the `id` of the `<input>` which is what the question was asking.

Comment: Can you tell a common approach to have multiple datepickers that differs from each other in design and look?

Comment: @xcy7e The example code uses the id of the input control, so you can adapt your css per control.  For example, `.ui-datepicker.MyControlId { color: black; }`.  If you want different styles for different screens or different areas of the page, you can adapt the code to check for the presence of some parent: `if ($('#' + this.id).parents('.some-parent-class').length) $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('a-special-class');`

Answer (score 3):

Jquery UI custom download allows you to add a custom prefix to your theme, say you added a prefix  ".datepicker_wrapper" you can add this class to your datepicker this way :

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      beforeShow : function(){
           if(!$('.datepicker_wrapper').length){
                $('#ui-datepicker-div').wrap('<span class="datepicker_wrapper"></span>');
           }
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to add css Classes for multiple datepicker.

**But remeber jQuery UI - v1.9.1 is not up-to-date last version is from 2012-10-25**

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker1" name='date1'/>
<input type="text" id="datepicker2" name='date2'/>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy',
    showAnim: '',
    beforeShow: function( input, inst){
      $(inst.dpDiv).addClass('just-yaer');
    },
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, 1));
        $(inst.dpDiv).removeClass('just-yaer');
    }
});

$('#datepicker2').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: false,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM',
    showAnim: '',
    beforeShow: function( input, inst){
      $(inst.dpDiv).addClass('just-month');
    },
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(month, 1));
        $(inst.dpDiv).removeClass('just-month');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.just-yaer .ui-datepicker-prev,
.just-yaer .ui-datepicker-next,
.just-yaer .ui-datepicker-month,
.just-yaer .ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}

.just-month .ui-datepicker-prev,
.just-month .ui-datepicker-next,
.just-month .ui-datepicker-year,
.just-month .ui-datepicker-calendar {
   display: none;
}
```

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/g6mnofu2/27/

Answer (score 0):

I would simple set an attribute and use it instead of the class.
in this case you dont need to remove anything because it will be overridden

```
$('input').datepicker({
   beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
       $('#ui-datepicker-div').attr("inputId",this.id);
   }
});
```

the to affect in JQ

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div[inputId=your_ID_here]')
```

in CSS

```
#ui-datepicker-div[inputId=your_ID_here]{}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#departure-date, #return-date").datepicker({
    // other options...
    beforeShow: function (input, instance) {
        // Add a custom className to the datepicker element
        $(instance.dpDiv).addClass("my-datepicker");
    },
    // other options...
});
```