# Custom css for only few jquery datepickers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a few Jquery datepickers on form.

```
$('#start, #end').datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy',
    onChangeMonthYear: function (dateText, inst) {
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, 1));
    }
});

$("#fulldate").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});
```

I need to hide some fields in first datepicker calls, and nothing change in last call. If i wrote something like this it change all instance of datepicker.

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar, .ui-datepicker-month {
   display: none;
 }
```

Thx for help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832622/how-to-add-a-custom-class-to-my-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: Thx. I dig in beforeShow and i found solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works perfect for me:

```
$('#start, #end').datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy',
   beforeShow: function(dateText, inst) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('hideCalendar')){
            $(inst.dpDiv).addClass('calendar-off');
        } else
            $(inst.dpDiv).removeClass('calendar-off');
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function (dateText, inst) {
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, 1));
    }
});
```

css:

```
.calendar-off table.ui-datepicker-calendar {
     display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the event **onSelect** on datepicker as follows

```
$('Your-Selector').datepicker({
onSelect : function(){
}
});
```

for further documentation refer [this link](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect)

hope this helps .......

Comment: Thx. But beforeShow more convenient.